# Show that if $1 \le x < y$, then $\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{x} < \frac12(y - x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that if $1 \le x < y$, then $\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{x} < \frac12(y - x)$

I squared both sides of the inequality, but it seemingly leads nowhere.

$(\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{x})^2 = y - 2\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x} + x$

$(\frac12y - \frac12x)^2 = \frac 14y^2 -\frac 12xy +\frac14x^2 = \frac12(\frac 12y^2 -xy +\frac12x^2)$

I'd like to use the fact that $y - x$ is positive. Not sure where that would be useful.

Can somebody, please, nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$y - x = \left(\sqrt y - \sqrt x\right)\left(\sqrt y + \sqrt x\right)$

Comment: $\sqrt y - \sqrt x = \frac {(y - x)}{\sqrt y + \sqrt x} < \frac {(y - x)}{2}$ since $\sqrt y + \sqrt x > 2$ because the smallest $x$ is one and $y > x$?

Comment: @JayZ yes. ${{}}$