# If $x_1 = 1, y_1 = 2$, then show that $y_5 - x_5 < (\frac12)^{45}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Provided: $x_{n + 1} = \sqrt{x_ny_n}$ and $y_{n + 1} = \frac12(x_n + y_n).$

Possibly the exponent of $\frac12$ is a typo or maybe not. My strategy is to brute-force it by solving for all $(x_i, y_i)$ with $2\le i \le 5.$ But it produces a horrendous looking number. Besides, the answer given in the back of my book is $y_{n + 1} - x_{n + 1} < \frac 18(y_n - x_n)^2.$ I have two problems here - I don't know how they arrived at that answer and also how the answer proves the given inequality. Although, I suspect we still have to substitute $(x_i, y_i)'s$ into the given answer. I would appriciate some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the given inequality,

$$y_5 - x_5 < \frac1{2^3} (y_4 - x_4)^2 < \frac1{2^3} \left(\frac1{2^3} (y_3 - x_3)^2 \right)^2 < ... < \frac1{2^3} \times \frac1{2^6} \times \frac1{2^{12}} \times \frac1{2^{24}} \times (y_1 - x_1)^{16} = \frac1{2^{45}}$$

You can prove a more general inequality for $y_n - x_n$ using the same idea.

To prove the given inequality,

$$y_{n+1} - x_{n+1} = \frac12\left( x_n + y_n - 2\sqrt{x_n y_n} \right) = \frac12(\sqrt{y_n} - \sqrt{x_n})^2$$

On the other hand, $\sqrt{y_n} - \sqrt{x_n} < \frac12(y_n - x_n)$. To prove this, first prove by induction that for all $n$, $1 \le x_n < y_n$, then see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666011/show-that-if-1-le-x-y-then-sqrty-sqrtx-frac12y-x) question.

**Edited:**

Therefore,

$$y_{n+1} - x_{n+1} \le \frac12(\sqrt{y_n} - \sqrt{x_n})^2 < \frac12 \left( \frac12(y_n - x_n) \right)^2 = \frac1{2^3} (y_n - x_n)^2$$

Comment: I love your detailed answer. Real cool.

Comment: At a first glance I thought I understood, but I am not very clear on how they came up with the coefficient $\frac {1}{2^3}.$ Can you clarify that, please.